# Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell Snapin: Incorrect Windows PowerShell version 3.0. Window PowerShell version 2.0 is supported in current console

Tags: .net, windows, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have SharePoint 2010 on my machine, for development purposes, and I made the mistake of upgrading to .Net 4.0 and PowerShell 3.0.

The work around, running powershell with the -version 2.0 or -v 2 switch/arguement doesn't completely work.

**So, this question is how do I add the Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell snapin in Powershell, on a Machine that has the .Net 4.0 framework?**

TRY 1:

```
PS> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.
PS>  Get-SPSite('http://myServerName/')
Get-SPSite : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.18052 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.
```

OK, So I TRY 2:

```
PS> powershell.exe -version 2.0
PS> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
Add-PSSnapin : Incorrect Windows PowerShell version 3.0. Windows PowerShell version 2.0 is supported in the current console.
At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

I've also tried setting the target of the shortcut.
And uninstalling the windows update that ends in q

So, thats my error that I cannot find any information on: 
**Incorrect Windows PowerShell version 3.0. Windows PowerShell version 2.0 is supported in the current console.**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a recent SharePoint 2010 update i am able to add the powershell snapin, while running powershell in version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work for me if I call

```
    powershell.exe -version 2.0
```

from the Command Prompt instead of calling it from Powershell.

Comment: Nope, John D., I tried running powershell from the Command Prompt but I'm getting the same error as, from above, 'TRY 2'.